# New Facebook Developers interface: 1024x1024 App Icon

Tags: facebook

Facebook recently changed the interface on https://developers.facebook.com/ . Previously, when you edited an App there, you were able to set a 16x16 icon, a 75x75 icon for the app (and some other sizes).

Now in the new interface, there is only an option to upload the small 16x16 icon and a larger 1024x1024 icon (plus different "Banners").

Presumably, the large icon is used (and downscaled) wherever something larger than the small 16x16 icon is needed. For instance, on https://developers.facebook.com/apps the App's icon is from the 1024x1024 image. If the App still only has the 75x75 image, that icon is still used. And I am guessing that the large 1024x1024 image is also used in the "App Store" of Facebook.

But can anyone tell me where else *exactly* this 1024x1024 image is used by Facebook? (If there are any other places.)
An on that note, is there any documentation where the different "Banners" are used?

Answer (score 2):

I've just added a 1024x1024 icon for my Android/iOS app - this large icon is shrunk to 65x65 px in the Chrome/Safari page that is opened (one with the app icon and the user's avatar icon, plus what permissions the app is requesting) in order for the user to authorize the app.

No doubt it would also be used in the FB popup that web pages launch in order to authorize via facebook

I imagine that this 1024x1024 icon will be used everywhere an icon is needed - except, in the Insights Panel I noticed that the 16x16 icon was used.